# NSLog( @"%d", 123456) produces 123,456

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Objective C, Xcode 15.0.1

Is there a way to eliminate the pretty comma? "%i" doesn't help.

Comment: Your `NSLog` line produces `123456` for me.

Comment: I assume I've gotten something out of whack with my environment, some setting somewhere. I'm hoping someone has run into this.

Comment: I get `123.456`, it's the notation in System Prefs.

Comment: May be by printing  number with `NSNumberFormatter`? Why number format in NSLog is bothering you?

Comment: Willeke, thanks! Cy, I also log strings of comma-separated numbers, so commas within numbers are visually confusing.

Comment: I was able to change the comma to a space, but there's no option without a comma, period, or space.  Raptor, what's your setting to get 123456? Xcode 15.0.1, Sonoma 14.1.1, in case it matters.

Comment: I see the thousands separators for `NSLog()` but only when running from inside Xcode.

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"%@", @(123456))` or `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", 123456])`.